# get ListView item in button OnClickListener inside it from custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an android ListView, inside each row there's a button. This is the code of my custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CheckInSArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {
    CheckInFunctions checkFuns;
    String check_id, watcher_id, user_id;
    FragmentManager fm;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

public CheckInSArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<JSONObject> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getViewOptimize(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getViewOptimize(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ..... //various findViewById()

    user_id = jObj.get("user_id").toString();

    check_id = jObj.getString("check_id");

    viewHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!v.isActivated()){
                if (checkFuns.like(check_id, watcher_id))
                    v.setActivated(true);
            } else {
                if (checkFuns.unlike(check_id, watcher_id))
                    v.setActivated(false);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    .... //various variables
    protected Button likeBtn;
}

}
```

So here is the problem: when i click on the button the value inside the "check_id" variable is always the value of the first(from top to bottom) object in the listview (i assume it is the last instanced). How can i have the value of the object of the item where i am clickin the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
public class CheckInSArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {
    CheckInFunctions checkFuns;
    //String check_id, watcher_id, user_id; NOTE THIS
    FragmentManager fm;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    ...

    public View getViewOptimize(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ..... //various findViewById()

        final String user_id = jObj.get("user_id").toString(); //NOTE THIS

        final String check_id = jObj.getString("check_id"); //AND THIS

        viewHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!v.isActivated()){
                    if (checkFuns.like(check_id, watcher_id))
                        v.setActivated(true);
                } else {
                    if (checkFuns.unlike(check_id, watcher_id))
                        v.setActivated(false);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    ...

}
```

All variables declared final are accessible from within the inner class.